# ListView hieght depend on contet size

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create custom dialog and the height depend on content, because the content keeps changing.

**More Explain :** when I use Column I can set the size of height depend on content just using `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`.

**By the way I tried to change ListView to Column but it's not working**

```
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
   children: <Widget>[
       Container(
           child: Text(
                    "Heder"
                  ),
                ),

       Container(
           width: 300,
           child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        ListView(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                            Text("hello"),
                          ],
                        ),
                     // Another widgets used inside Stack
                     ]
                   ),
                )
              ]
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your container in `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget

```
  ...
  Expanded(   
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
                Text("hello"),
              ],
            ),
            // Another widgets used inside Stack
          ]),
        ),
      )
    ...
```